# How to prevent webpack to fail build on eslint error?

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, vue-cli

i used the default vue-cli command to create a vue project.

When webpack is building, it fails, as shown in the image:

[image]

I am not using any special webpack configuration. What am i doing wrong?

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "firebase": "^7.6.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess with the new eslint/webpack stuff, this is default behaviour.

So this is my workaround in my .lintrc.js file:

`'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 1`

Answer (score 5):

You can force ESLint to always emit just warnings instead of errors by webpack configuration. That will not stop your build as you expect. You need to set `emitWarning` option to `true` in your webpack.config.js file.
eg.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          emitWarning: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

You can read more in the documentation https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader#errors-and-warning

Comment: Have you tried to add "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    }, to your .eslintrc.js file?

Comment: Sorry for the bad formating, i am not able to write it nice.

Switching off no-console would work, but i don't want that in my codebase. Sometimes i need it for debugging locally, but then the build fails, as described.

Comment: ok, i think with the new eslint/webpack stuff, this is default behaviour. So this is my workaround: `'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 1`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This works at first, but then fails after hotreload when I make a single code change

Comment: `eslint-loader` is deprecated see https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-loader

Answer (score 1):

NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin is now automatically enabled in webpack 4, when mode is either unset, or set to production. So even ESLint warnings will fail the build. No matter what error settings are used for eslint-loader, except if emitWarning enabled.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/eslint-loader/#noemitonerrorsplugin